# How to add curl HTTP Headers for authentication in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, http-headers

I want to add the HTTP headers for authenticating Udemy API access.Can someone tell me as to how to add the headers.I already have the client id and secret key.I want to access the API from a PHP page. 
https://developers.udemy.com/
Here is the code i tried using:

```
$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id:MY_ID','X-Udemy-Client-Secret:Secret'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$results= curl_exec($ch);
echo $results;
```

Output:

```
Blank Page
```

Can someone point out what the problem might be?

Comment: Why are you running a curl request and then file_get_contents? echo $results;

Comment: @drmarvelous I basically want to access the API feed which is in json format in a wordpress theme.But it is not authenticated.

Comment: Correct, but you're already doing that with curl.  Right now you are performing TWO different requests (albeit mal-formed)

Comment: I did that and it gives me a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @drmarvelous wrote, you perform **two** requests (1st - by CURL, and 2nd - by `file_get_contents`) which does the same. Wherein the result of CURL request is not actually used in your script. It use the result of `file_get_contents` request which is performed without authentication parameters. Because of this you getting `Unauthorized` error.

So you have to use the result of CURL request:

```
...
$json = json_decode($results, true);
print_r($json);
```

**Update:**

You have to ensure you use valid URL for API request, i.e. value of `$request` in your code should be valid URL. Also, ensure you pass valid authentication parameters (`Client-Id` and `Client-Secret`) by HTTP headers.

Furthermore, since API is secured, you have to disable SSL peer verification by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false`.

So the code should look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id: {YourID}','X-Udemy-Client-Secret: {YourSecret}'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$results= curl_exec($ch);
echo $results;
```

Comment: Hey i tried making those changes and have updated the post but when i use echo $results; It gives a blank page.

Comment: But what you've expected? Some message?
I think that a blank page is a normal response to **authentication** request. I.e. "no messages" means "OK" (no errors).

Comment: Oh i was expecting a feed as shown on the api page.I want to access the feed data.

Comment: You cannot get data on **authentication** request. It's only for authenticating user, not for getting data

Comment: Even if i enter a wrong API secret key it shows a blank page.For accessing the data after authentication what do i have to do?

Comment: I've looked at the API page. It seems I was a bit wrong. API doesn't requires separate authentication request. Instead it requires authentication parameters which have to be included in **every** API request. See my updated answer.

Comment: So basically i have to send a request for all the courses links i want the data from? and Thank you, it works like a charm.